# Using Cantor's Diagonalization to Show Polynomials are NOT Countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've seen the proof for why the polynomials with integer coefficients are countable, however if you use the method Cantor used for showing the real numbers aren't countable, can't you reach the conclusion that the polynomials aren't countable? If you just list every such polynomial, can't you always find a polynomial not listed? Or is this only applicable to power series?

Comment: If you think so, why not write a proof?

Comment: If you mean just polynomials with real coefficients, then just the grade 1 polynomials: $x+a$ have the same number of elements as $a$ has possible values.

Comment: From which set are the coefficients of your polynomial? From $\mathbb R$, from $\mathbb N$ or from $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: If you talk about polynomials from $\Bbb R[x]$, then clearly $|\Bbb R|\leq|\Bbb R[x]|$. If you talk about polynomials with coefficients from a countable set ($\Bbb{Q,Z,N}$), http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564479/question-about-cantors-diagonal-argument/564492#564492 contains a plethora of references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for power series, but not polynomials.  The reason is that polynomials only have a *finite* number of nonzero coefficients, and the diagonalization argument will produce something with an infinite number of nonzero coefficients (since in general the $n$-th polynomial will have degree less than $n-1$ and have a zero as its $n$-th coefficient).

Comment: In fact the argument that there must be an infinite number of nonzero coefficients in the series produced (even if working over say $\Bbb F_2$, so that the fact that almost all constant polynomials in the list produce a nonzero coefficient does not suffice) is precisely... the diagonal argument (if the series produced were a polynomial, it would have to be on the list).

Answer (score 0):

If you try an apply cantor's diagonalization argument to polynomials, you would need allow them to be infinite. Basically polynomials would be able to have any coefficients $a_k$ in the following expression,
$\sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_k x^k.$

However, a polynomial is typically defined to be finite. For some $n$ we have $a_k = 0$ for $k \ge n$. This limitation makes the set of polynomials countable.